# Where do i use the TextWatcher implementation?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I mean, in which function should i use a text watcher?
I've tried to use it in the onResume() function, but that didn't work.

I'm trying to check one of each characters entered in my EditText box while the user is typing. More specifically, I gave the user a riddle and the answer is 'SOS'. The answer goes in the EditText box and I want to check each character right after its input (I've added a max length attribute to the edittext box so it won't exceed 3). When I find a wrong character, i want to set an X icon image visible, and the opposite if the character is correct.

Here is my TextWatcher code snippet:

```
final EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTxt_three);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
        {

        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) 
        {

        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
        {
            for(int i=0;i<editText.length();i++)
            {
                if(i==0)
                {
                    img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.icon1);
                    if(s.charAt(i)!='s' || s.charAt(i)!='S')
                        img.setVisibility(1);
                    else
                        img.setVisibility(0);
                }
                if(i==1)
                {
                    img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.icon2);
                    if(s.charAt(i)!='o' || s.charAt(i)!='O')
                        img.setVisibility(1);
                    else
                        img.setVisibility(0);
                }
                if(i==2)
                {
                    img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.icon3);
                    if(s.charAt(i)!='s' || s.charAt(i)!='S')
                        img.setVisibility(1);
                    else
                        img.setVisibility(0);
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

In short, where should i use this code?
Feel free to simplify my code if you think of something :)

Comment: Put this code in onCreate.. Unless you want to block the text watcher until some event..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use textwatcher  in onCreate, the codes below helps you i think .

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView img,img2,img3;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
            {

            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) 
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                String s = editText.getText().toString();
                  for(int i=0;i<editText.getText().toString().length();i++)
                    {
                        if(i==0)
                        {
                            img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);                           
                            if(s.charAt(i)!='s' || s.charAt(i)!='S')
                                img.setVisibility(1);
                            else
                                img.setVisibility(0);
                        }
                        if(i==1)
                        {
                            img2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                            if(s.charAt(i)!='o' || s.charAt(i)!='O')
                                img2.setVisibility(1);
                            else
                                img2.setVisibility(0);
                        }
                        if(i==2)
                        {
                            img3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
                            if(s.charAt(i)!='s' || s.charAt(i)!='S')
                                img3.setVisibility(1);
                            else
                                img3.setVisibility(0);
                        }
                    }

            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: Hmm.. my if's are apparently wrong. Or the whole method i thought of. Still though, i'll figure it out. Thanks :)